# Reorder iostat output with time next to the device column

Tags: text-formatting, columns

I am trying to reformat the iostat data.

Current output:

```
TimeA

Column1 Column2 Column3
disk1    10GB     small
disk2    20GB     medium
disk3    30GB     large

TimeB

Column1 Column2 Column3
disk1    10GB     small
disk2    20GB     medium
disk3    30GB     large
```

And I want as below:

```
TimeA  Column1 Column2 Column3
       disk1    10GB     small
       disk2    20GB     medium
       disk3    30GB     large

TimeB  Column1 Column2 Column3
       disk1    10GB     small
       disk2    20GB     medium
       disk3    30GB     large
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
     NF == 1    { time_value = $1 }
     NF == 0    { if (time_value == "") print }
     NF == 3    { printf("%-7s", time_value); time_value = ""; print }
    '
```

- If a line has just one value, it’s a time value. 
  Save it.
- Print blank lines that occur between a time line and data lines. 
  Do not print blank lines after data lines.
- The first time you see a line with three values,
  print it with the saved time value at the beginning. 
  Then erase the saved time value. 
  Subsequent data lines (until the next time line)
  get printed with spaces at the beginning.